# Airplane rotations and turning

Tags: game-engine

I have a airplane model and it's controlled by moving the mouse. At the moment, when it turns it simple turns - that's it. What I want is for it to turn like a real plane - so rotating left/right when it turns left/right.
How could I achieve this?

**Images:**
[image: my logic]

As you can see the movement is simple and the turning is with the mouse - so how can I make it more like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but why not to use multiple axes for rotation? You didn't give us specifics on how you do the rotation, but if you're using simple motion actuator, you could just set the rotation values on another axis. Tho I think you should give us some more information on your current logic setup and on what exactly would you like to achive if this answer is not sufficient.

Comment: @Krzysztof Kansy ok, I've added a picture of my logic editor and what I want to happen when turning

Answer (score 3):

You are very close in your setup. you only need one more mouse look actuator.

The reason why you need another actuator is because you currently have nothing to make the airship rotate along the Y. Adding another mouse look actuator can fix that.

I have also changed the settings slightly from what you had, because I think it behaves better with these values.

[image]

The first mouse look actuator does the roll.

[image]

The second mouse look actuator does the pitch and yaw.

[image]

With both of them together, it behaves just like a *[flying fortress of total monkey awesomeness](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/531/5426)*

[image]

With the actual mesh from the flying fortress only with BGE materials

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it seem to stay rotated a certain way until I move far in the other direction @X-27

Comment: technically a real plane would stay banking until it's flight controls changed and it began flying differently.

Comment: but my game doesn't have realistic controls